# Stop thread, not extending class

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've been looking around some anwers given here but i don't get exactly the solution to my problem: I don't want to create a new class and extends runnable or thread.

I have a service that when created must check every 10 secs some stuff and the calls needed can't be done from the main thread, so onStartCommand() method I do the following:

```
    mThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {

                    // some code

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                        Log.i("Exception", errors.toString());
                    }
                }
```

Now, when i call onStopService() i want to stop this thread. The method stop() is deprecated so I'm using interrupt():

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    mDelete.interrupt();
    mDownload.interrupt();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

As I expected, it throws InterruptedException because the thread is sleeping when calling interrupt.

Is there any way to stop the thread without creating a new class and extend from runnable or thread?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you want to start a thread without creating a class that implements Runnable or extneds Thread(stopping a thread without creating it is not possible obviously)?

Comment: Your code here already creates a subclass - an anonymous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), you can use this code inside your thread:

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // We've been interrupted, and returning from the run method will stop your thread.
        return;
    }
```

However, in general it is better avoid infinite loop service. You should consider to stop your service when the work is done, and restart it (using an `AlarmManager`) when a new work is required. I will not repeat the code for use `IntentService` and `AlarmManager`, since Eugen Pechanec has given you a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1) Extend your service from `IntentService`.

This type of service is used for short granular operations and it runs on a background thread so you can access network. Do your work in method `onHandleIntent(Intent)` instead of `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`.

2) Schedule this service using `AlarmManager` (the following code will work in an activity).

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent i = new Intent(this, Service.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

long nowElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
long tenMinutes = 10 * 60 * 1000;

am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, nowElapsed, tenMinutes, pi);
```

Notice the word "inexact". That means that the interval won't be exactly 600000 milliseconds. It is more energy effective.

The `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` flag is for proper rescheduling.

3) Cancel the `PendingIntent` when you don't need it anymore. After this your service will not run automatically until you enable it again.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Service.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
if (pi != null) pi.cancel;
```

More about using alarms: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

More about `IntentService`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html